# How to check if app is brought to foreground to handle a custom scheme url?

Tags: ios, uikit

How to tell if the app is brought to foreground by sending a custom scheme url (not tapping on the app icon)?.

If the app is not currently running, the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called and we can check by using value of key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` in `launchOptions`, but in the case that app is already running, the only option we have is `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and it provides no information about the reason why app is brought to foreground.

Is there any other way to tell such the difference (app brought to foreground by custom url and app brought to foreground by tapping app icon)?

Answer (score 0):

Your app will receive the 
`-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` call from the OS via your App Delegate.

If your app wasn't running, the app delegate receives `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` first, THEN `-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`.

If your app was already running, you only receive the latter.

Comment: I meant how to tell that app is brought to foreground by custom url scheme but not by tapping on app icon

Comment: I think the real answer is "you shouldn't care."  If the app was launched with a URL (or simply brought the FG via a URL), you'll receive the `openURL` call.  If the user simply taps the app icon, you won't be receiving that call.

Comment: In our case, we need to save a log of 'enter foreground' event along with the cause (for analytic purpose)